# Perl - looping through Hash and changing the internal iterator counter?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash:

```
my %myHash= (
    "Key1", "val1",
    "Key2", "val2",
    "Key3", "val3",
    "Key4", "val4"
);
```

I loop though it

```
open(EXEC, '-|', "my Shell Command") or die "Can't exec: $!\n";

# Now read the output just like a file
while(my $line = <EXEC>) {
    chomp $line;             # remove the newline from the read line
    $line =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # remove leading or trailing whitespaces
    # reset the internal iterator, and loop through the hash
    keys %myHash;
    while(my($key, $val) = each %myHash) {
        # find if it matches anything - and store it
        my $keyWordIndex = index($line, $key);
        if ($keyWordIndex != -1) {
            # if the cols/vals query isnt empty, add comma to the end
            if (length($queryCols) > 1) { $queryCols .= ", "; }
            if (length($queryVals) > 1) { $queryVals .= ", "; }

            # do some more stuff here
            my $subLine  = substr($line, $someStart, $someLength);
            # now build the columns and values to write out to the DB
            $queryCols .= $val;
            $queryVals .= "'$subLine'";
        }
    }
}
# prepare the DB query
$command = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO $table($queryCols) VALUES ($queryVals)")
or die "Could not prepare the query - $DBI::errstr\n";

# execute the database update
eval { 
    my $db_results = $command->execute();
};

close(EXEC);
```

What I do in the `while` loop is go through a text, line-by-line, and seek a match to one of the `keys`. The above `while` loop is nested inside another `while` loop that reads the text line-by-line. If there is a match, I concatiante a string which then I use to update my database. The string I concatinate is the value of the matching key in the hash.

So my SQL query will look something like that:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(header1, header3, header2, header4)
VALUES ('substr1','substr3','substr2','substr4');
```

The problem is, that the text can contain a repeating line with a repeating key, which has a duplicate info which I don't care about.

The `keys %myHash` [resets](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) the internal iterator. Is there a way to modify the internal iterator if I found a key, so I will not iterate over it again after I reset it?

Comment: Why iterate over hash at all when you can do simple `exists` lookup?

Comment: I could be wrong, but it sounds like you're trying to map fields in your data file to column names in your database. You can do that without messing with hash internals; please show an example of your data and we can help you come up with a better solution. (Also see [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: I am not sure if `exists` will help me here. What I am trying to do is just simplify stuff for me. I have an output, with many lines. I want to match a line to a regex. The regex is a substring of that line. I then want to remove that regex from the line, and that will give me the value I am looking for. This value is then uploaded to the database. The regex is the `key` of hash, and the column where the substring will go to in the database is the `value` of the hash.

Comment: Can you actually put that into the question and add example code for it?

Comment: That portion of the code has nothing to do with the question of whether or not it is possible, or if there is a way, to reset the internal iterator and then modify it to skip certain elements in the hash?!

Comment: No, but I think there is a better approach and for that I need to understand what you are trying to do. :-)

Comment: With no disrespect intended, I had a hard time understanding what you were doing exactly. Does this "The problem is, that the text can contain a repeating line with a repeating key, which has a duplicate info which I don't care about." Mean that you don't want to create a string out of a concatenated key and value where the value exists elsewhere in the hash?

Comment: @simbabque - ok, you are right. I have added the other loop in. As you can see, I write a shell command, and I want to read the output, line-by-line. Then I want to match each line to an already know regex which is stored in my `%hmyHash`. So I loop through the hash, in order to find the matching regex, if any. If I do find it, I add it to the columns and values variables - and then I want to write them to the database. But because some lines have a repeated info - columns are repeated - and that throws an error. I tried to delete $hash{$key} but it did not seem to help.

Comment: Yes, but for each shell output, I want to repeat the lookup only once for each regex string. NM. It works now after I added the delete

Comment: It looks like `%my_hash` should be an array of pairs rather than a hash, because you're not using the regex string to access the corresponding value in the hash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update

Now that you've explained a little better what you need, this code should do it for you. It keeps a hash `%wanted` that contains the names of the columns to be
inserted and their corresponding values

You must be careful about any whitespace that appears in the shell command's output between the column name and the data value: either the regex in the hash must allow for it or you must include a `\s*` in the pattern being applied

```
my $table;

open my $cmd_fh, '-|', 'my shell command' or die "Can't exec: $!";

my %wanted;

while ( <$cmd_fh> ) {
    s/\s+\z//;
    while ( my ($re, $column) = each %my_hash ) {
        if ( / $re (.*) /x ) {
            %wanted{$column} //= $1;
        }
    }
}

my @values        = values %wanted;
my $columns       = join ', ', keys %wanted;
my $placeholders  = join ', ', ( '?' ) x @values;

my $sql = sprintf 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)', $table, $columns, $placeholders;
my $command = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$command->execute( @values );
```

---

If I understand you correctly, you want to pick those keys from your hash that appear anywhere in the output of your shell command. Then you want to execute an SQL `INSERT` statement using those keys as column names and the corresponding hash values as the data to insert

You've made things much more complicated than necessary. This code reads the entire file into variable `$lines`, and then `grep` is called to pick those hash keys that appear anywhere in `$lines`

From there it's simple to generate a comma-separated list of column names and a corresponding list of placeholder question marks that can be used to create an `INSERT` statement that is passed to `prepare`. The list of hash values is passed to `execute` which will quote them properly acording to data type

```
my $lines = do {
    open my $cmd_fh, '-|', 'my shell command' or die "Can't exec: $!";
    local $/;
    <$fh>;
};

my @matching_keys = grep { index( $line, $_ ) >= 0 } keys %my_hash;
my @values        = @my_hash{@matching_keys};
my $columns       = join ', ', @matching_keys;
my $placeholders  = join ', ', ( '?' ) x @values;

my $sql = sprintf 'INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)', $table, $columns, $placeholders;
my $command = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$command->execute( @values );
```

You're clearly used to writing in a different language. You should stick to lower-case letters for lexical identifiers. Perl reserves capitals for global identifiers such as package names

Comment: This is what I think the OP was really trying to do. I would make the minor addition of quoting the table and column names with `quote_identifier` just in case they contain special characters, although that seems unlikely.

Comment: It is NOT what I was trying to do. The KEYS of the hash  are only the regex I compare each line against. Once a matching regex is found for that string - the VALUE of the hash is used as the database's columns. The actual data I enter into each of the columns is the rest of the string - without the regex (the KEY of the has)

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: That should have gone into your question. You managed to fool at least two first-class Perl programmers into thinking is *was* what you wanted

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: Do you realise that `index` doesn't do a regex match? It simply looks for one substring within another. That is one reason why your example code was misleading. It would also have help enormously to show an example of the output from your shell command

Comment: @Borodin what did you just call me?! :D

Answer (score 2):

Since you do not control the order of the keys, setting an internal pointer won't help. You can simply [`delete`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html) the key once you found it. Make a copy of your hash first if you want to hang on to the *used* ones or move them into a new hash, maybe `%used`.

Comment: I'm on a phone, no documentation links for now.

Comment: OK, it worked, I placed the delete inside the first while loop, and I copy the original hash into a temp hash before the first while loop. That fixed it.

Comment: @KingsInnerSoul: If that's the only change you made, and the keys of your hash are really regex strings, then your code can't be working as `index` doesn't search for regex patterns

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you just want to delete the key from %myHash once you've found it.

Comment: Kinda, but not really. I look through the hash for each newline I get in order to match that line with the "key" of the hash which is the regex for matching. I will want the hash intact for the next line I read in.

Comment: then I don't get it; you are already only looking once for each key in each line; what is it you want to prevent looking for?